# Podio API JS - Update relationship field of a Item

Tags: podio

Using NodeJS, I am trying to update relationship field which link to another app (contacts-leads). I have try all combination but still getting error. I think I have the necessary data to post, app_id, item_id, external_id..etc. I need help with forming JSON structure.

```
p.request('put','item/<Item_Id>/value', data)

var data {....}

app_id:'<app_id>'
value:'<value>' (value is the app_item_id of the link to application; that is the number in URL)
app_item_id: '<app_item_id>'
external_id:'<external_id>'
```

I was able to update non-relationship field without problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, going to answer my own question. That will work for single app link, not sure about multiple ones.

```
data = {
  "<external_id>": {
     "apps": [{"app_id": <app_id>}],
     "value: <app_item_id>
   }
}
```